# Port Forwarding - Server responds to remote Java request, responds via local browser, can't be reached in remote browser

Tags: java, html, tomcat, portforwarding

I am hosting an Apache Tomcat instance on a server which is used to display a web page.
It needs to be remotely accessible via a browser.
The web page runs normally via localhost and I have setup port forwarding to make it remotely accessible.
I have tested the port forwarding with Java and successfully connected to the sockets.
Despite being able to connect to the socket, when I attempt to access it via a remote browser is returns "site can't be reached".

Locally
Local Browser - Web page runs as expected on localhost:8080

Remotely
Socket test - pass
Remote Java Request - Responds with full html of web page
Remote Browser - Site can't be reached

Does anyone know why only the remote browser portion would fail, while remote requests sent through Java would work?

Comment: It could fail due to your fire wall configuration on the local system (blocking external requests), or it could fail because any system between the local system and the test system was configured to block such requests.

Comment: Do you know what configuration would allow a simple remote request sent via Java, but reject a request sent via Chrome?